# Cambiar nombre de variables Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, base-de-datos, variables

me gustaría cambiar el nombre de todas las variables que tengan el mismo nombre.¿Sabeis algun comando? Android Studio

Comment: Puedes cambiar el valor de cada variable, pero el nombre de esta mmm. aparte como le colocas el mismo nombre a todas las variables? ahah

Comment: Puedes usar refactorización, selecciona la variable y Shift+F6, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mejor usa la funcion de "Refactoring" (Refactor) que tiene el propio Android Studio.

Paso a paso:

- Boton derecho sobre la variable
- Escoger "Refactor" -> Rename
- Escribir directamente el nuevo nombre
- Pulsar INTRO

Comment: Tal como está,esto es mas un comentario que una respuesta. Trata de explicar un poco mas donde está esa función y como usarla para que la pregunta sea de mas calidad.

Comment: Ampliada la explicación...

Comment: No se debe  "Escribir directamente el nuevo nombre", **en realidad se debe editar el nombre de la variable**.

Answer (score 2):

En Windows:

Buscar : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Buscar y Reemplazar en una sola clase: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Buscar y reemplazar en un proyecto completo: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

en OS X ,es similar, solo reemplaza <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> con <kbd>Command</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Una de las funciones de la IDE Android Studio es precisamente la refactorización

> **Refactorizar** significa hacer pequeños cambios para mejorar la estructura de un programa sin afectar su funcionamiento.

Implica renombrar variables en todo tu proyecto de una forma segura sin afectar el funcionamiento del mismo.

Existen dos formas de Activar la refactorización:

**1)** Selecciona la variable y activa la refactorización mediante la secuencia:
 <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2)** Selecciona la variable o dando clic derecho sobre la misma, seleccionas:

`Refactor` > `Rename`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De estas dos formas puedes activar la refactorización y puedes realizar el cambio en el nombre de la variable, la cual cambia globalmente en tu proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿No has dicho lo mismo que conteste yo ?

Comment: @luisgulo ¿Me asignas -1 porque en tu opinión mi respuesta es lo mismo que la tuya ? Mi respuesta abarca las **opciones para realizar la refactorización**, una explicación de las opciones, además explica que es refactorización. ¿Para ti es lo mismo?